# fontsize appear to be not working with revtex for long tables

Tags: revtex

`\fontsize` doesn't seem to work when used in `revtex4-1` with long tables.

```
\documentclass[11]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont
\begin{longtable}{l l r}
\hline
Reaction & Rate Constant & Ref       \tabularnewline
     & 2nd order     &           \tabularnewline
     & 3rd order     &           \tabularnewline
\hline
& & \\
Electron impact & & \\
Electron impact & & \\
\hline 
\end{longtable}
\end{center}                                                        

\end{document}
```

Does someone knows what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `revtex4-1` class redefines the `tabular` related commands in a way that seems to conflict with the inner commands of `longtable`, which assumes the default ones.

Comment: @egreg the class also redefines all the main longtable internals as well.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed! Well, you should know them better than I do. ;-)

Comment: So, is there an alternative way to reduce font size of the whole long table with revtex?